# cftextarea controls not showing when loaded with jQuery ajax .get()

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, coldfusion

I've got a CFTEXTAREA field, which behaves normally when viewed on its own, but when its loaded via jQuery get() method, the controls do not appear.

ie
The cftextarea is on a product detail pane.
ON the left side of the page is a list of products to edit.
clicking on one on the

elements, loads the product detail pane via ajax and jquery (simulating an old school href)

the content is loading in, but the toolbar does not appear.
hitting the page on its own, the toolbar shows.

here is the jquery (working fine)

```
$("#productList li").click(function(event) {
$.get(
    'editProduct.cfm',
    {id:$(this).attr('id')},
    function (response) {
        $('#productDetail').html(response);
    }
);
});
```

and here is the CFTEXTAREA call: (working fine when not loaded via jquery/ajax)

```
<cftextarea enabled="yes" name="nutrition" rows="5" cols="25" richText="yes"  toolbar="Basic" html="yes" >#DESCRIPTION#  </cftextarea>
```

---

It'd be nice to be able to use cftextarea on forms loaded in via ajax.
is it possble?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is include the `<cfajaximport>` tag on the page that contains your jQuery functionality. ^__^

Comment: jcaito, surround inline code with backticks (**`**) in order to prevent tags being considered HTML.  For other formatting functionality, see the [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.